# Convert utf8 string to ISO-8859-1

Tags: go, utf-8

How to convert a `utf8` string to `ISO-8859-1` in golang

Have tried to search but can only find conversions the other way and the few solutions I found didn't work

I need to convert string with special danish chars like `æ`, `ø` and `å`

`Ã¸` => `ø`
etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Keep in mind that `ISO-8859-1` only supports a tiny subset of characters compared to Unicode. If you know for certain that your `UTF-8` encoded string only contains characters covered by `ISO-8859-1`, you can use the following code.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "golang.org/x/text/encoding/charmap"
)

func main() {
    str := "Räv"

    encoder := charmap.ISO8859_1.NewEncoder()
    out, err := encoder.Bytes([]byte(str))
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    fmt.Printf("%x\n", out)
}
```

The above prints:

```
52e476
```

So `0x52`, `0xE4`, `0x76`, which looks correct as per https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1 - in particular the second character is of note, since it would be encoded as `0xC3`, `0xA4` in `UTF-8`.

If the string contains characters that *aren't* supported, e.g. we change `str` to be `"Rävv"`, then an error is going to be returned by `encoder.Bytes([]byte(str))`:

```
panic: encoding: rune not supported by encoding.

goroutine 1 [running]:
main.main()
/Users/nj/Dev/scratch/main.go:15 +0x109
```

*If* you wish to address that by accepting loss of unconvertible characters, a simple solution might be to leverage `EncodeRune`, which returns a boolean to indicate if the rune is in the charmap's repertoire.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "golang.org/x/text/encoding/charmap"
)

func main() {
    str := "Rävv"
    out := make([]byte, 0)

    for _, r := range str {
        if e, ok := charmap.ISO8859_1.EncodeRune(r); ok {
            out = append(out, e)
        }
    }

    fmt.Printf("%x\n", out)
}
```

The above prints

```
52e47676
```

i.e. the emoji has been stripped.

Comment: Stripping of unsupported characters is a horrible "solution" which produces complete garbage in many situations. Please don't do that unless you have a good understanding and complete control of the entire data pipeline; or perhaps expose the option  to the end user, but default to raising an error rather than outputting corrupted results.

Comment: The very nature of the question suggests a likely scenario whereby this is going to fail. As I said, `ISO-8859-1` only covers a tiny subset of characters catered for by Unicode. The very nature of converting from `UTF-8` to `ISO-8859-1` either implies loss or failure. OP didn't indicate the scenario where they are making this conversion, so I've provided both options - either attempt and error, or accept that certain characters cannot be converted.

Comment: @nj_ how to I install `golang.org/x/text/encoding/charmap`? I'm fairly new to golang.. It will not fail because it's for pure text/file names etc

Comment: ahh.. haha.. instructions in the compiler error :)

Comment: your solution is stripping valid danish chars like `ø` which in utf8 is `Ã¸`

Comment: If I set `str` to `"ø"` then the supplied code will output `f8` - which is the correct way to encode `ø` in `ISO-8859-1`. Refer to the table under https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1#Code_page_layout

Comment: I don't disagree, I just wished the answer was more explicit about the drawbacks. It seems, every minute there's a new visitor to Stack Overflow who thinks ruining their output is better than explicit failure, and then we are left to clean up the mess, sometimes years later. Good job security for those with the patience and the stamina, but frustrating for users and bad for efficiency and ultimately the planet.

Comment: @tripleee ok?? then tell my how to add filenames to a tar.gz with utf8 chars? ;)

Comment: That depends on the underlying file system's support. The tar file format itself accepts arbitrary bytes in file names, with the exception of slashes (which are reserved as directory separators) and null bytes.

Comment: @tripleee then try reading this... https://superuser.com/questions/60379/how-can-i-create-a-zip-tgz-in-linux-such-that-windows-has-proper-filenames/60591#60591 Just to sum it up: `Basically it's a horrible mess and if you can avoid distributing archives containing filenames with non-ASCII characters you'll be much better off.`

Comment: That doesn't contradict what I said. If you have a problem, it's because your file system doesn't know what to do with UTF-8. I can't help but think switching to Latin-1 is objectively worse in every possible way (though you'd need to use an obscure Windows legacy code page like 437 to really reach the inner circles of the inferno if that's your actual goal). To actually meaningfully solve the problem in this situation, you'd have to convert to pure 7-bit ASCII instead, perhaps then with some sort of escaping convention to represent nonprintable characters losslessly.